# cmake with Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, cmake

I'm using CMake v3.5.0 with MSVC 2015.  I'd like to generate a Windows Phone 8.1 project.  In the [CMake Docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-windows-phone) it shows how to do this by setting `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` to `WindowsPhone` and `CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION` to `8.1`.

However, when I do that it falls down:

```
> cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 ARM" -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=WindowsPhone -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=8.1
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was on a dev machine that had upgraded through several versions of Visual Studio.  With a fresh Windows 10 image, I installed Visual Studio 2015 and it works fine with CMake.